# Graphs of Categories Exercise

Tags: category-theory

I have completed the following introductory exercise from [The Joy of Cats](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/17/tr17.pdf), which I am self-studying. There are no easily available online solution sets, but I am looking to check my work. The exercise is as follows (G(**A**) is the graph of the category **A**):

[image: Joy of Cats]

I have concluded that every one of these graphs is realizable as a category, but it seems unlikely the question would have been written this way in that case.

> Am I mistaken that each of these graphs represents a category?

The categories I chose are as follows:

(1) $\{0\}\leftrightarrows\{1\}\rightarrow\{2\}$ where the arrows represent the only possible functions between these singleton sets.

(2) $\{0,1\}\leftleftarrows\{1\}\rightarrow\{2\}$ where the two left-pointing arrows are the functions $f:1\mapsto 0$ and $g:1 \mapsto 1$, and the remaining arrow is the unique function $h: \{1\} \to \{2\}$.

(3) Let the three vertices be singleton sets and the arrows be the unique maps between them.

(4) Let the vertices be the sets $A=\{0,1\}$ and $B=\{2,3\}$. Let the functions be

$f:B\to A$ sends $2\mapsto 0$ and $3\mapsto 1$.

$g:A\to B$ sends $0\mapsto 2$ and $1\mapsto 3$.

$h:B\to A$ sends $2\mapsto 1$ and $3\mapsto 0$.

Note that $f$ and $g$ are inverses.

> Is each of my examples a category, and do they each correctly determine the graphs shown?

Edit:

It's clear now that (1) cannot be a category, because there is no arrow from the leftmost object to the rightmost object, but that should exist to obey composition. However, (4) is a bit less clear.

Comment: You should try to describe more precisely your categories for (1) and (4). They should be closed under composition.

Comment: What does the $G(A)$ represent?

Comment: Oh, I see! So the function from $\{0\}$ to $\{2\}$ should be in there too, but it isn't since the graph doesn't include such an arrow?

Comment: G(A) represents the graph of the category A - edited!

Comment: I mean to ask what is the graph of a category? Don't you draw identities? Is the graph supposed to represent all the nonidentity arrows of the category?

Comment: The author states that identities are implied in these diagrams.

Comment: If that is the case, then (4) is wrong since there is no drawn arrow representing $hg$.

Comment: Thanks! If I'm correct then, (1) and (4) are not representable but (2) and (3) are?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you noted, (1) does not come from a category, but (2) and (3) do.

Now, for (4) think about this: suppose that some category produces the given graph, so there are arrows $g:A\to B$ and $f,h:B\to A$.

- Who is $gf$?
- Who is $gh$?
- Who is $fg$?
- Who is $hg$?
- Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to the commenters, I have a clear solution. (2) and (3) are correct realizations of the graph as a category (though it's not necessary that we represent them as concrete categories).

For (1) call the vertices from left to right $A$, $B$, and $C$. There's no arrow from $A\to C$ but there is from $A\to B$ and $B\to C$, so this cannot be a category since it is not closed under composition.

For (4), call the vertices $X$ and $Y$ from left to right. Then $gh:Y \to Y$, and since there are no loops, $gh$ is the identity on $Y$. Similarly, $hg:X\to X$ is the identity on $X$, so $g$ and $h$ are inverses. But that means $g$ and $f$ must be inverses for the same reason. Thus $f=h$ by uniqueness of inverses, which is a contradiction. Thus (4) cannot be the graph a category.